# How to install TensorFlow with Pip?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I'm trying to install tensorflow and I get this error. How do I fix this? [image: 1]

I am very new to coding so small words would be helpful. P.S. I'm using miniconda3 if that's important

Comment: try pip install termcolor first. .. it looks like maybe you have an antivirus that prevents that package for some reason ... try disabling it while you install

Comment: Conda handles TensorFlow in an interesting way. Have you already tried the steps listed [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)?

Comment: Please don't post images of text output. Always copy\paste it into your question instead.

Comment: Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install tensorflow using pip. Thank you.